# Group by identifier and divide every indicator in the group by the value in the first row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Taking the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'Group': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'P': [100,101,96,200,204,208], 'PL': [99,100,94, 199,203,207]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    Group   P   PL
0   1      100  99
1   1      101  100
2   1      96   94
3   2      200  199
4   2      204  203
5   2      208  207
```

For each group in the 'Group' column, I want to divide every element in the 'PL' column by the first element in the 'P' column. These values would be stored in a new column

The desired output would look like this:

```
    Group   P    PL   Division
0   1       100  99   0.99
1   1       101  100  1
2   1       96   94   0.94
3   2       200  199  0.995
4   2       204  203  1.015
5   2       208  207  1.035
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) values per groups and divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df['Division'] = df['PL'].div(df.groupby('Group')['P'].transform('first'))
print (df)
   Group    P   PL  Division
0      1  100   99     0.990
1      1  101  100     1.000
2      1   96   94     0.940
3      2  200  199     0.995
4      2  204  203     1.015
5      2  208  207     1.035
```

Another idea with `map`:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('Group').set_index('Group')['P']
df['Division'] = df['PL'].div(df['Group'].map(s)
```

Comment: how the string `"first"` connected with `GroupBy.first` ?
can you just use any method from the GroupBy object like that?

Comment: @SyntaxError - yes, you can use any function from [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) if aggregate data. For not aggregate function like `cumsum` it is not necessary, then use `df.groupby('Group')['P'].cumsum()`